# What is the difference npm start and firebase serve?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, npm, firebase-cli

I've created an app that makes calls to Firebase. The Firebase API has given instructions to test the application, via `firebase serve` and `firebase deploy`. I know that `firebase serve` creates a local server instance at `localhost:5000`.

Is there a difference in this case between running `npm start` and `firebase serve`, besides the port number? Are they just the same thing, if you have a react application that uses Firebase?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

npm scripts are defined in your project's package.json.  So, if the "start" script defined there is "firebase serve", then there is no practical difference between `firebase serve` and `npm start` for that project.